# Getting user's location Android

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I'm looking for the best way to get the user's location. I've found there is two main ways :

- Using `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` from Google
  Play Services
- Using `android.location.LocationListener` from Android APIs

**My question is simple: which one is the best?**

At the moment, I'm using the first one but I'm facing issues: when using cell network, my location is never retrieved.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's a third to consider: `com.google.android.gms.maps.LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener`. It too has an `onLocationChanged` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is first one. **com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener** abstracts fiding location from your code.
For sample code look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049535/513413) please. It works fine for me with cell network or wifi.

Comment: "abstracts fiding location from your code" is the only reason to prefer the first option? Thanks. I've read your code and I've something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Though this one post is really old but I thought I should answer it so that it clears my concept on this as well. See the below link:

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location
```

It says:

> Note that the My Location layer does not return any data. 
>   Should you wish to access location data programmatically,
>   use the Location API.

So, i think using com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener from Google Play Services could be an easier approach but if you want to access the location data(exactly in my case) and want to do something with it, than it is best we use android.location.LocationListener from Android APIs

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the developers of the [new Gps and sensor toolkit app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kennis.gsat) for android. We did look into this api during development, but found that for most purposes using `android.location.LocationListener` is suitable. The other interface is alot more complicated and would take a little longer to implement. I suggest `android.location.LocationListener`.

The `Location` class that is given to you by the interface provides many methods that you could use to get latitude, longitude, speed, distance to another point, bearing, etc...

Also look into `GpsStatus.Listener` and `GpsStatus.NmeaListener`
for data about satellites.

Comment: hey, don't forget to download the app . (**

Comment: You're wrong, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener is easier to use, and I don't care about speed nor distance.. I'm just looking for getting the user's location the easiest way.

Comment: first of all, is is a matter of opinion. Second all you need is Location.getLatitude() location.getLongitude() and this can be accomplished in as little as 11 lines. DO YOUR RESEARCH

Comment: and if you want location from network you simply LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER as opposed to LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

Comment: Just found someone do it in 8 lines

Comment: Its true @worlboss is correct "In my opinion" and a little research would into the features and implemenntation would have done you good.

Comment: Also nice app @worlboss